# В панели Git редактора Atom не отображаются измененные файлы

Tags: git, atom

В панели Git редактора Atom под управлением Win7 не отображаются измененные файлы, в чем может быть причина. На другой машине на Win10 все работает. Помогите разобраться.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Причины могут быть разные. Файл внесен в .gitignore, в файле нет изменений, панель гит показывает другой проект, панель гит не показывает изменения автоматически и нужно ее обновлять вручную, еще какая-нибудь другая причина

Comment: @Эникейщик как узнать, какой проект отображает git?

Comment: @Эникейщик в Atome должен лежать репозиторий Gitа?

Comment: Атом это редактор, в нем ничего не может лежать. Я его в жизни не разу не видел, поэтому ответить на вопрсы не смогу. Просто перечислил вам вероятные причины, как вы спрашивали.

Comment: А гит проект тоже перенесён на новую машину или только рабочие файлы?

Comment: Любопытно, что дерево-то показывает статус файлов, и папка `.git` в корне присутствует.

Comment: @Roman да, так и есть

Comment: @D-side вот-вот, и отслеживает изменения. При этом git bash все видит, а панель - нет

Answer (score 1):

Cудя по тому, что справа внизу нет упоминания о git и ветках (возле слова HTML), у Вас нет репозитория в этой папке. То есть либо Вы открыли внутренную папку (и каталог .git находится выше), либо гит репозитория просто нет для этого проекта.

Comment: как правильно подключить репозиторий для этого проекта?

Comment: я сначала работал с git bash для этого проекта. Я просто только начал работу c Atom и не могу понять, как в нем работать с gitом

Comment: продолжайте работать с git bash. Так будет проще.

Comment: ))))))))))) Это шутка?

Comment: мне нужно в общем узнать, как работать с git-панелью в атоме

Comment: первое - установите git bash. В любом случае. Потом откройте атомом папку с своим проектом, но в этой папке должен быть каталог .git